# Determining the date in a timezone that is different than Time.zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

My Rails application makes use of `Time.zone` so that each user can set their own timezone and see timestamps in the correct zone. However, I would like to have some content that is only available for one day, but for that one day to be the same 24 hours for all users.

In order to do that, I was going to use `if Time.zone.today == Time.zone.local(year, month, day).to_date`, but obviously that will just check the 24 hours that the day is the same in the current (ie. users') timezone.

Is there any way to do this without having to change `Time.zone` to the timezone I want to use first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use the Time.zone, use server time. There isn't any need to get into what time the user thinks it is if you only want it to be the same 24 hours for everybody.

```
if Time.today == Time.local(year, month, day).to_date
```

Comment: Duh, that's a great point. I got so caught up in terms of using `Time.zone` that I didn't think about just using `Time`!